# Error while Modifying an Existing Maintenance Plan for SQLSERVER 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am having an issue with sql server 2012 sp1 management, when ever i try to modify an existing maintenance plan i get the following error:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object. (microsoft.datatransformationservices.vsintegration)

I looked everywhere for a solution with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried re installing SSMS?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to open your maintenance plans in SQL Server Data Tools and upgrade them to 2012.

this is the similler post 
[SQL Maintenance plan issues](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f845c1f5-4a41-4445-ab12-f22b66e87678/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-sql-server-2012?forum=sqlgetstarted)

Comment: Thanks but how do i do that?